# Infinite loading realtime database Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from the Realtime Dababase from a flutter app but it won't working. It keeps loading infinitely(and doesn't display any errors). I'm already using Firestore in the same app and it works like a charm!
Here's a screenshot of my database
[image: RealtimeDatabase]
and here's my code:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Text(valueRealtime ?? ''),
    onPressed: () async {
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123");
      DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();
      print(event.snapshot.value); // { "name": "John" }
    },
  ),
```

I'm emulating an iPhone for the simulation just in case it has anything to do with it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you're having. Is the `print(event.snapshot.value)` not outputting anything?

Comment: No, I used a print before and after, and it never gets to the after print

Comment: Interesting. Some debugging questions: 1) Can you read from the database anywhere else in your code, for example just in your `main` method? 2) Can you *write* to the database anywhere in your code? 3) Is there any error show in the log output?

Comment: 1:  Can you read from the database anywhere else in your code, for example just in your main method? No, the app seems frozen (in a white screen) because it cannot pass through the await (test it with a print before and after). 2.  Can you write to the database anywhere in your code? No, same thing, it does not pass through the await. 3) Is there any error show in the log output? No, not even if I check the All Exceptions and Uncaught exceptions

Comment: I'm wondering if the SDK can't find your database, because the URL is missing from (or wrong in) the config. Can you redownload the `Google-Service.info.plist` (and re-add it to you app), or hardcode the URL in your code (`FirebaseDatabase.instance("your database URL here").ref("users/123")`)?

Comment: Redownloaded the Google-Service.info.plist and it worked!! Thank you so much! You saved me hours :)

Answer (score 0):

As Frank said, try to redownload the Google-Service.info.plist (and re-add it to you app) and it may solve your problem!